# Buffer in QGIS covers the entire map

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to create a buffer in QGIS, but it covers the entire map

My project CRS is WGS 84/Pseudo-Mercator(EPSG:3857). I also set the CRS of layers on this.

What is wrong?

Comment: Never, *ever* perform any measurent operation in Web Mercator -- distances in that projection are useless. And buffers in WGS84 degrees are similarly useless (and huge, since one degree is 60 nautical miles at the Equator)

Comment: What buffer distance are you using? How did you set the CRS:s of the layers? You should [reproject them](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer), not [Assign projection](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisassignprojection) or just right-click them (if they arent already in 3857, but the projection got lost).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your data is located try using UTM CRS. Take a look at this tutorial: https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/introduction-to-qgis.html#reproject-and-buffer

If you are not sure which zone you are in, just go to this website: https://epsg.io then search for "country name" UTM.